# System.getProperty multiple default values for list of strings

Tags: java, string, list

I am pretty new to Java and was wondering if this would work:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        KriaStubRiskAnalysis kriastubriskanalysis = new KriaStubRiskAnalysis(System.getProperty("KriaIE4N10Check.valChromedriverpath", "C:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe"),
                                                                              System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.url", "https:********"));
        kriastubriskanalysis.stub(System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valFuntionalReference","20210824123229ID0635"),
                                System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valMRN", "21DK108241232291T1"),
                Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valTotal", "4")),
                new String[]{System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valRiskLevel", "4")},
                Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valWait", "2000")));
```

Is there a way to set:

```
new String[]{System.getProperty("kriastubriskanalysis.valRiskLevel", "4")},
```

To have multiple defaults values? I want to test the for loop I have in my code and need `valRiskLevel` to have multiple values I can iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can parse value yourself. Just split it by "," and pass all values separated by ",".